# sql query selecting from two tables - return results from one table if there are none in the other table

Tags: mysql, sql

i am running this SQL query:

```
SELECT a.retail, b.cost 
from call_costs a, call_costs_custom b 
WHERE a.sequence = b.parent 
 AND a.sequence = '15684' 
 AND b.customer_seq = '124'
```

which returns both `a.retail` and `b.cost` if the row exists in `call_costs_custom` but if the row does not exist, i want to show just `a.retail` using the `WHERE` clauses for `a. (call_costs)`

Comment: You need a left join

Comment: By the way: Are `sequence`and `customer_seq` strings? I am asking because the string literals you compare them to only contain digits. If the columns are numeric, you should compare them with numbers: `AND a.sequence = 15684 AND b.customer_seq = 124`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an outer join, i.e. a join that keeps records from the first table even when there is no match in the second table. Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or short `LEFT JOIN` hence:

```
select cc.retail, ccc.cost 
from call_costs cc
left join call_costs_custom ccc on ccc.parent = cc.sequence and ccc.customer_seq = '124'
where cc.sequence = '15684';
```

Answer (score 2):

From W3Schools:

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1),
>   with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL
>   in the right side when there is no match.

```
SELECT 
    a.retail,
    b.cost 
FROM 
    call_costs a
LEFT JOIN 
    call_costs_custom b 
        ON 
    a.sequence = b.parent 
        AND
    b.customer_seq = '124'
WHERE 
    a.sequence = '15684'
```

Comment: this returns both but if there is no row in `call_costs_custom` it returns no results

Comment: This is because the outer join is not properly written. All criteria on the outer-joined record belongs in the `ON`clause. Just as the quote says: "The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match". So `b.customer_seq = '124'` is never true in that case and you are where you were with a mere inner join.

Comment: Edited to reflect Thorsten's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is not 100% clear 
but here is my attempt:

```
SELECT COALESCE(b.cost,a.retail)
FROM call_costs a
LEFT JOIN call_costs_custom b 
ON a.sequence = b.parent 
  AND b.customer_seq = '124'
WHERE a.sequence = '15684'
```